# How to Invoke ICorDebug

Tags: clr, guid, mdbg

In "MDbg Sample.zip" projects, invoke the function from COM Module as: 
[ComImport, Guid("3D6F5F61-7538-11D3-8D5B-00104B35E7EF"), InterfaceType((short) 1)] public interface ICorDebug { ... } The question is where to find the Guid("3D6F5F61-7538-11D3-8D5B-00104B35E7EF"), i can not find it in the regedit, but how to connect the ICoreDebug interface with the COM module?

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the registry. That guid is the IID, ICorDebug doesn't support remote access so there is no reason to register a stub/proxy against the interface.

How you get an instance depends on what versions of the runtime are installed, but these days "everyone" has CLRv4 installed, so you access via the ICLRMetaHost.

- Use [CLRCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537633(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an implementation of [ICLRMetaHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233134(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Use ICLRMetaHost to find the [ICLRRuntimeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233121(v=vs.110).aspx) for the desired version of the runtime.
- Use [ICLRRuntimeInfo.GetInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233135(v=vs.110).aspx) to request an implementation of ICorDebug using CLSID_CLRDebuggingLegacy.

Comment: Hello @Brian Reichle, I have programed according to your prompts: hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeHost));  hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (LPVOID*)&pRuntimeHost);   But when I debug the code ,there is notification as:There is no type information available in the symbol file for <mscoreei.dll 0x01179c50>. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but `CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost` looks out of place. (ICLRRuntimeHost is what you use to host a runtime in your process, it's not normally used to create an ICorDebug)

Comment: Thank you. Actually what  I really want  to do  is  to find  a way to read out  the detail  information such  as Guid etc from CLR. If I use new version CLR, I hope  I can invoke such  as  Icoredug by myself.